# Как правильно составить query builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

Есть сущность User с полем registrationDate(дата регистрации). Как правильно составить query builder, чтобы получить массив пользователей, зарегистрированных в переданный день и месяц?

```
public function findByDayAndMonthOfRegistration(int $day, int $month)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->....
}
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю что надо найти всех пользователей, которые зарегистрировались в определенный день определенного месяца любого года?

Comment: да, всё правильно

Comment: ну я бы сделал двумя запросами. сначала получил минимальную дату регистрации, взял из нее год, потом в РНР сформировал массив всех дат, которые подходят под условие, и передал этот массив в WHERE IN (?). Так будет задействован индекс. В противном случае запрос будет перебирать все записи по одной

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть 2 варианта.

Зависит от версии вашей ОРМ

```
->andWhere('MONTH(b.registrationDate) = :month')
->andWhere('DAY(b.registrationDate) = :day')
```

Если докторина будет ругаться, то можно посмотреть как решить эту проблему вот тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826836/how-can-i-use-sqls-year-month-and-day-in-doctrine2
(добавив поддержку функций)

Если версия ОРМ совсем старая и обновляться нельзя, то как лайфхак можно вот так

```
->where('SUBSTRING(b.registrationDate, -5) = :registrationDate')
->setParameter('registrationDate', $d->format('m-d'))
```

Если пользователей очень много.
И вам важна скорость запроса.
То можно создать виртуальную колонку месяц и день, сделать индекс по ним.

ALTER TABLE b ADD registrationMonth int(8) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(b.registrationDate)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL;

Ну и искать просто по этой колонке.